# Adding additional time to Launch Screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, launch-screen

```
#import "RecipeBookViewController.h"
#import "RecipeDetailViewController.h"
#import "RecipeIngredientViewController.h"
#import "RecipeInstructionViewController.h"
#import "Recipe.h"

@interface RecipeBookViewController ()

@end

@implementation RecipeBookViewController {
    NSArray *recipes;
}

@synthesize tableView = _tableView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Is there anyway for me to add a second for the launch screen to appear longer? Where would I add the code?

Answer (score 1):

You could display a UIViewController with a full size UIImageView holding your splash image as your UIWindow's `rootViewController`.

In your viewDidAppear, have a method that change that UIViewController being called with a `performSelector:afterDelay:`

```
[self performSelector:@selector(changeViewControllerMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use sleep method in root view controller's viewDidLoad Method.

```
sleep("seconds")
```

This will pause further execution for the seconds you passed.

Comment: I try adding it to the view controller but it sleep like forever lmao

Comment: I think you want that splash screen should displayed and execution should not stop, Right?

Comment: then may you can show the splash screen image in root view controller and when you finish your background task then remove that image from root view with animation. So when splash screen goes and then your controller also showing the same image as splash screen.

Answer (score 0):

Add `sleep(numberOfSeconds)` to `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in your AppDelegate.h.

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    sleep(10);
    return YES;
}
```

Although, Apple suggests that you should not do this with your launch images.

> [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html):
>   Because users are likely to switch among apps frequently, you should make every effort to cut launch time to a minimum, and you should design a launch image that downplays the experience rather than drawing attention to it.